# Is it correct to use 'will' twice in this sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense, redundancy

I know there is no general rule of using 'will' twice in a sentence so I want to understand where I can use it

example:

> I will appreciate it if you **WILL** send me my bag

question:

I can't grasp allowance and forbiddance of using 'will' twice but according to this [video](https://youtu.be/hk1AvFgOsSo?t=642) I concluded that sometimes it is possible

is it right using of 'will' *(twice)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can – but usually not as you put it. There's a pertinent explanation in Swan's *Practical English Usage* (260.1):

> We use *will* with *if* to talk about what will happen because of possible future actions – to mean ‘if this will be the later result’. Compare:
>
> > *We'll go home now if you **get** the car.* (condition)
> >      *We'll go home now if it **will make** you feel better.* (result)

So no one would say this:

> I will appreciate it if you will send me my bag.

because you're essentially saying that you'd be happy to show gratitude if that will make them send you your bag, as though there'd previously been an argument between you and the other person who said:

> I'm not sending you your bag if you don't thank me beforehand!

However, your sentence would never be interpreted as such – outside the bizarre context I made up above, and even then it would be rephrased into something like

> I'll say "thanks" if that'll make you hand it over.

which is still weird but less weird than the original – but rather as a non-native English speaker's attempt to say what [BillJ](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/31780/billj) said in [their comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131815/is-it-correct-to-use-will-twice-in-this-sentence#comment265194_131815) (a closing quotation mark added):

> "I would appreciate it if you would send me my bag" would be the usual polite phrasing. "I would" can be reduced to "I'd" in informal contexts.

Comment: I agree. However, I'd contract you would to You'd on the second instance. In the USA at least. Abroad I'd be more articulate. 

Answer (score 2):

I will appreciate it if you send me my bag.

Case one: will + present after if. No will after if.

I would appreciate it if you sent me my bag.

Case two: conditional in first clause, simple past in second

Case two can also be: I would appreciate your sending me my bag.

To use two wills you need another type of situation.

If you will [**do some action**], I will [**do some other action**].

Answer (score 1):

While there is no general rule limiting the number of times the verb "will" can appear in a sentence, there is a problem with your example.  Look at it this way, as written your sentence is two command actions (I will if you will!)  It reads oddly to most English speakers because, well, without context "them's are fightin' words".  It's considered impolite to compound commands.

The most common way to express the original sentence, as already pointed out, is:

"I would appreciate it if you would send me my bag."

Rather than a double command, this is a conditional-consequence pair (if this then that, or... if send then I would appreciate).  This is considered polite as it indicates an obligation would be incurred (to show appreciation) if the action is taken.

(Note that it is improper to say, "I would appreciate it if you could send me my bag."  Unless there is a reason to question the sender's physical ability to send the bag (could) the request is always one of permission (would).  See "can I..." vs. "may I...".  If you really want to be sarcastically funny, reverse the would/could pair...  Suddenly the sentence is quite rude!)

Another way to say the sentence is:

"I will appreciate it if you do send me my bag"

This is another form of the conditional-consequence pair, but the use of the initial command (will appreciate) implies sarcasm (playful or angry).  It suggests the sender can't be trusted to follow through with his or her action whether he or she agrees or not.

To bring us full circle, let's give context to the moment, such as the situation of two people daring one another to take a possibly risky action such as jumping into a pool for the first time:

"I'll do it if you'll do it!"

So, you see, the question isn't "can I use 'will' multiple times?" but "should I use 'will' multiple times?"  And that depends on what you're trying to say and why you're trying to say it.

Answer (score 0):

Using "*will*" multiple times is not a problem

> I **will** say that if you **will** use **"will"** more than once, it **will** not be a problem to understand your sentences, but it **will** depend on context.